# wget.download() only works for some links

Tags: python, web-scraping, wget, urlrequest, urlparse

I have a list of some links (which are pdf files). I'm running `wget.download()` for each link in the list. However, only some of them get downloaded and then I get:

```
File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I also tried to use `r = requests.get(link)` but the issue is still the same and additionally, I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp
```

Example of link that does not get downloaded:

https://cnds.jacobs-university.de/courses/sads-2020/p6.pdf

If I open the link on my browser, I get the download. Also, this method was working until a few months back. Idk why it's not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as of yet, but have you tried downloading the files with a browser manually? If that works then the issue must be that wget can't reach the target for some reason.

Comment: It's a good place to start.  I have also occasionally seen weird behavior around SSL/TLS certificates, as well as bizarre behavior through proxies, that masquerade as other HTTP errors.

Comment: Yes, if I open the link on my browser, I get the download. Also, this was working until a few months back. Idk why it's not working anymore @Frank

Comment: Is there some reason you chose `wget`?  I'd tend to use `requests` directly.

Comment: That doesn't work either. The issue is still the same, only some links get downloaded @Frank